# Carrying out multiple synchronous tasks with a micrcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I am making a robot which has several mechanisms on board. To keep things simple, let us say it has 2 DC motors, and 2 servos. Most of the time, the servos are not doing anything, and the 2 DC motors are moving in the same direction (using an L239D motor driver). This is using an AVR MCU by the way (likely an ATmega 328). The motors use PWM signals.

So suppose I send a command to turn one motor CW, the other CCW, and actuate the two servos. I need this to all happen at the same time. So how does this work?

If something like threading exists, I would create one thread for the motors, one thread for one servo, and another for the second servo so that they all go off and do their thing at the same time. But I don't think threading exists, or is common at least.

So how would I run multiple commands at the same time?

Comment: They are not going to be at the same time, never. However, the delay will be so small to matter. What is the maximum delay that you can tolerate? Why do you need to start them at the same time?

Comment: If you really need parallel processing, it can be achieved using FPGA, where you can program few gates that will do parallel tasks. Majority of projects doesnt need real parallelism, few uS doesnt make any difference in mechanical systems where inertial forces doesnt allow fast changes in movement direction. Of course it depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors involved that make this work well enough for devices requireing less than magic to operate them.

**(1) The world passes by slowly when you are a microcontroller:** DC motors and servos operating at full cry appear to be standing still to a microcontroller. eg a motor running at 10,000 RPM rotates 10,000/60 ~= 160 revolutions per second. So one revolution takes 1000000/160 =~ 6,000 microseconds. One degree of rotation required 6,000/360 ~= 16 uS. Depending on the uC concerned, 16 uS is starting to get noticeable, but if a processor can handle say 10 MIPS it will excecute about 150 instructions in the time that it takes a 10,000 rpm motor to rotate 1 degree. Generally speaking a uC at this sort of speed can be close enough to being N places at once to a degree that appears instantaneous to most real world devices.

There are real-world devices that start to make the above assumptions a bit suspect, but in most cases all shall be well.

**(2) True simultaneous operation or close to simultaneous operation is easily enough achieved when needed.** 8 or 16 or even 32 digital bits can be written genuinely simultaneously (ignoring possible nanosecond level skew). If a decision is made in advance to implement a set of inter-related actions at a certain time, they canm be implemented essentially simultaneously by sharing a single processor write to port. In practice consecutive writes to ports will occur quite quickly enough for any time differences to be indiscerniblke by mere mechanical devices.

In the case of PWM signals, these will usually be implemented at a frame rate which is slow compared to processor cycle times. An exception may occur if the PWM uses a PLL clock which is some multiple of the processor clock, but even then a whole frame is liable to be many processor cycles lomg. eg a processor may have a (slow) 200 ns cycle time. A PLL may clock a hardware PWM unit at say 50 MHz or 20 ns/bit. Even then, an 8 bit PWM register will produce a 160 nS frame rate which is of the same order of length s the uC cycle. Few and extremely far between are the hardware devices that need a sub 1 uS PWM frame rate. Anyone attempting to drive a power system at this speed would face horrendous switching loss issues and you would need very special requirements to do this.

IF some action requires responses which are synchronised to better than a uC cycle time this can be achieved by preloading data and triggering a simultaneous write either to a port or ports at once or by clocking external hardware. It happens, but it's not usually needed in home or consumer level equipment.

Answer (score 3):

BYour MCU is not a muti core system. Thus it is **impossible** for it to run things at the same time. It was also the same during the age of single core computers.

In order to solve your problem, you should use the same "trick" that is used by common OS: Scheduling.

Basically, you perform a little bit of motor control A, then a little bit of motor B, then a little bit of servo A, then B, and you loop. If you do this very quickly. You system will behave as if theses tasks are running in parallel.

Concerning the implementation, it is dependent on the platform and what you want to do.

1. If you don't have strict power requirement for instance, I would go with a RTOS such as FreeRTOS. This works on AVRs and is quite easy to use. This would solve your scheduling problem.
2. You can implement a basic scheduling system using a simple infinite loop system, that continuously executes different non-blocking state machine, one per task. But here, it's much difficult to respect strict timing constraints, if you have some.

But finally, if it's a hobby project the question is : What do you want to learn about ? A basic scheduling ? A RTOS ? Another proposed approach? I am sure they would all solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Blup pointed out, the micro can only do one thing at a time.  However, it can alternate between different things so fast that it *effectively* can do multiple things at a time.

Yes, multitasking is a useful abstraction, and I use it quite a bit in more complex microcontroller firmware.  Full blown preemptive multitasking is overkill on a microcontroller and comes with some significant costs.  However, cooperative multitasking can be very useful.  I use mostly PICs and have simple cooperative multitasking systems for PIC 18 and the dsPICs.  I probably use these in over half the projects on those parts.  Cooperative tasking allows the task switching to be quick and simple and requires no mutex structures, critical sections, and the like that add complexity and cycles to preemptive systems.

Usually dedicating a task to each asynchronous input stream is a useful abstraction.  For example, if the micro is controlling 2 motors and receives commands over the UART, then I'd dedicate a task to receiving and handling the UART input stream.  Essentially the task becomes a state machine with the state variable being the PC.  Depending on what exactly the motors needed, they might be handled in the PWM interrupt from data left around by the command processing task.  If the micro has to do a bunch of other little and latency-tolerant things, then another task that uses a main event loop architecture is usually appropriate.  This task would blink the status LED according to the current system status, possibly check any user buttons once per ms (a long time for a micro) and do the debouncing, check for various "oh crap!" conditions like exessive motor current and initiate appropriate shutdown sequences, etc.

If you are willing to use PICs for this task, you can have my multi-tasking (and a lot of other canned code) for free.  Look for files with "task" in their names in the SOURCE > PIC and SOURCE > DSPIC directories in the software installation directory after installing my [PIC Development Tools](http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm) Release.

Comment: Of course, Olin's *libraries* are in assembly language. As I understood it the bad way from my other experiments on multitasking, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @abdullah: When you're performing unnatural acts on the stack, you pretty much can't use a high level language. You can poke the necessary registers directly, but that will violate a bunch of assumptions the compiler could be making. Also, something as low level and frequently used as a task switcher is worth making as cycle-efficient as possible since it will be used many times as a resource to future unknown projects, some of which may need every cycle they can get.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, it will be possible to divide tasks into those which require very small predictable amounts of work to be done at arbitrary times in response to external events, moderately-small amounts of work to be scheduled at regular intervals, stuff which will hopefully be done reasonably expeditiously but has no particular timing requirement, and stuff which should follow a long-term program flow (e.g. a prompting user interface).  The asynchronous things are done by asynchronous interrupts; the scheduled things are done by a timer tick.  The non-time-critical things are done by a `poll()` routine that gets called while e.g. waiting for a button push, and the user-interface flow is handled using "normal program flow" [e.g. when the user enters a menu, program execution will enter a routine to handle that menu, and will only exit that routine when the user leaves the menu].

If the worst-case total time spent on asynchronous events in each tick is below the allowable timing jitter for the periodic events, and if the worst-case combined time for periodic events and asynchronous events in a tick is below the duration of the tick, then things are very simple.  If one has two sets of events which are supposed to happen at 1ms intervals, and if the worst-case time for each is significantly below 500us, it may be helpful to define an interrupt that runs every 500us, and handles the two events alternately.

Using a real-time operating system may allow one to meet a variety of complicated timing requirements in cases where a combination of fixed scheduling and fixed-priority interrupts would not be adequate, but in cases where the simpler methods would suffice using a real-time operating system may be overkill.

On some processors, if there is more than one task which requires a "logical program flow" rather than having a routine which always enters at the top and uses flags to control its state, it may be helpful to define a simple "task-switch" method.  On the 8051, if there exactly two such tasks, such a method would be:

```
_TaskSwitch: ; Assumes all registers may be freely trashed on a subroutine call
    mov a,AltSP
    xchg a,SP
    mov AltSp,A
    ret
```

Not much to it.  A four-instruction "operating system"!  To set it up, one must define a region of memory for use as the second task's stack, store to the beginning of it the address of the first routine to be executed using the second stack, and set AltSP just past that stored address.  The first call to TaskSwitch will then switch to that stack, pop the stored address, and start running code from there.

Note that the above code is hardly a real-time-operating-system, but I've used that approach on a number of projects.  Note that there is nothing in the task-switch logic to handle scheduling.  If one task has a lot of work to do but calls _taskswitch periodically to ensure the other task gets a chance to run, and the other task is doing nothing but waiting for a timer to expire, then each _taskswitch call will cause execution to switch to the second task which will then see that the timer hasn't expired yet and call _taskswitch to go back to the first.  All that task switching may seem wasteful, but in fact it happens in less time than a more sophisticated RTOS would spend determining that no task switch was necessary.

Comment: May I ask which sources you used or if you came up with this yourself (as a conclusion of years of experience and multiple sources)?
I find this extremely interesting and very well written. If I were to use this as a source, I might get some problems at school for not crediting the original author? I would love to read the sources you used for this. I'm sorry to bump such an old "thread". But it might be valuable for other users also.

Comment: @FuaZe: I can't offer you any particular sources, though googling `stack-switching cooperative multitasking` (one query, hyphenated as shown) pulls up some links that at first glance might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple embedded task scheduling architectures:

1) Round robin. Time slices are assigned to all processes in order.

2) Bottom halves. Most tasks use round robin architecture. The most important are tied to interrupt routines. That is, the interrupt sets a flag, and when the round robin cycle reaches a specific point in the cycle checks for the flag and if set, completes some actions.

3) Queue - a queue of tasks to execute is maintained. New tasks are added to the queue and executed ones are dropped.

4), 5) ... others that I do not know of ...

Comment: The most common approach I use is simply to have one main task along with one or more interrupt handlers that when triggered do their thing and exit, using flags or `switch` statements if they need to have logic that carries over from one invocation to the next.  In some cases, I might even go so far as to use a subroutine pointer, invoked something like: `isr_proc = (VOID_PROC)(isr_proc());`  Any function that is assigned to `isr_proc()` will, when executed, return the address of another such function which should be executed next time.

Comment: @supercat, the idea behind 2) in my post (and it is far from being mine idea) if that if the interrupt has to do heavy work, it generally sets a flag and exits. Then, when the round robin loop reaches an if(flag){slow block of code}, the less time-critical, but interrupt-dependant code is executed. Refer to [picoOS](http://picoos.sourceforge.net/features.html) - bottom halves.

Comment: I don't think of that as setting time-slices; I simply think of that as "doing stuff", though I should update my answer (should appear shortly).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in select cases it may be possible to have things happen at the same time: for example, in some chips you could do all of this by programming hardware timers, and do all the configuration before you enable them.  Then that common, single activation operation would kick off all these operations you have set up, with no relative delay (excepting section-to-section skew in the device itself).

But for the case in question, that's not remotely necessary - consider that the servos can't even start to update position until well into if not the end of the 1-2 millisecond servo pulse.  That's a long time for a microcontroller which could turn around and immediately write to a different peripheral.  And that's just the servo starting to move - the mechanism and will take time too.

In this case, you probably do not even want threading, or at least not a thread per peripheral.  More typically, you would just have a main program loop, or a common thread which handles each peripheral in turn.  Other parts of the program might deal with communication, planning, health monitoring, etc - but again with the exception of interrupt service routines to move data between I/O and software buffers, often on a system as small as you contemplate, all of the other tasks would simply be handled one after the other in a loop.